# How to Create a Menu With C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I create a menu with Switch but if operation in case 1 is wrong I want to press N to return to the beginning of case 1. I want to use IF-Else to do this and I want to press 1 after pressing N and return to the beginning.

Edit : When I press the N key, I need to write N twice to make the process happen, how do I fix it?

```
    switch (menu){

case 1:

do {
    redo = 0;

    printf("\n\nPlease write Worker ID Number : ");
    scanf("%s", &file_name);
    strcpy(out3, file_name);
    strcat(out3, filex);
    fout = fopen(out3, "wb");


    printf("Please Enter The Worker's First Name : ");
    scanf("%s", &user.firstName);

    printf("Please Enter The Worker's Last Name : ");
    scanf("%s", &user.lastName);

    printf("Please Enter Worker's Identification Number Again : ");
    scanf("%s", &user.UserID);

    printf("Please Enter Worker's Gender : ");
    scanf("%s", &user.gender);      

    printf("Please Enter The Worker's Birthday Date (dd/mm/yyyy) Format : ");
    scanf("%d / %d / %d", &user.day, &user.month, &user.year);

    printf("Please Enter The Nationality Of The Worker's : ");
    scanf("%s", &user.nation);  

    printf("Please Enter The Worker's Start Date (dd/mm/yyyy) Format : ");
    scanf("%d / %d / %d", &user.Sday, &user.Smonth, &user.Syear);

    printf("\n\n\tWorker Information is :\nFirst Name : %s\nLast Name : %s \nIdentification Number : %s \nGender : %s \nBirthday Date : %d/%d/%d\nNationality : %s\nDate of Start : %d/%d/%d", user.firstName, user.lastName, user.UserID, user.gender, user.day, user.month, user.year, user.nation, user.Sday, user.Smonth, user.Syear);


    for (;;) {

    printf("\n\n\tDo You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N\n");
    scanf("%s", &answer);       
    if (scanf(" %c", &answer)  != 1)
    return -1;



    if(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'){

        printf("\nWorker's information has been saved!\n");

        fprintf(fout, "Worker's ID : %s\nWorker's Name : %s %s\nWorker's Birthday Date :  %d/%d/%d\nWorker's Gender : %s\nWorker's Nationality : %s\nWorker's Start Date : %d/%d/%d", user.UserID, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.day, user.month, user.year, user.gender, user.nation, user.Sday, user.Smonth, user.Syear);
        fclose(fout);               


        break;

    }


    else if(answer == 'N' || answer == 'n'){

        printf("Press 1 to re-enter your information : ");
        scanf("%d",&answer1);

        redo = 1;
        break;  

        }


    }
    } while (redo);
```

Comment: Please provide a stripped down but [mcve]. All extra input-/output that doesn't belong to menu navigation is just distracting noise.

Comment: "_return to the beginning_" just put your code in a loop and exit from it ( use a _break_  or a test becoming _false_ for a _while_ or a _do while_ etc) when you do not want to return to the beginning

Comment: can you explain a little more explanatory?

Comment: @Exciless `/* ... */ case 1: { do { /* ... */ } while (something); } break; /* ... */`

Comment: @Swordfish I add the codes but it's not working can you look down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I fix it?
>
> can you explain a little more explanatory? –

Look at that example where there are 2 loops

- a "do while" to allow to reenter the worker information
- a "for" to ask again in case the answer is not y Y n or N

I use two kind of loops to allow you to see the difference

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct User {
  char firstName[32];
} User;

int main()
{
  User user;
  char answer;
  int redo;

  do {
    redo = 0;

    printf("Please Enter The Worker's First Name : ");
    if (scanf("%31s", user.firstName) != 1)
      /* EOF */
      return -1;

    printf("\n\n\tWorker Information is :\nFirst Name : %s\n", user.firstName);

    for (;;) {
      printf("\n\n\tDo You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N\n");
      if (scanf(" %c", &answer)  != 1)
        /* EOF */
        return -1;

      if(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'){
        printf("\nWorker's information has been saved!\n");
        break;
      }
      else if(answer == 'N' || answer == 'n') {
        redo = 1;
        break;
      }
      puts("invalid answer");
    }
  } while (redo);

  puts("done");
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please Enter The Worker's First Name : aze


    Worker Information is :
First Name : aze


    Do You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N
Y

Worker's information has been saved!
done
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please Enter The Worker's First Name : aze


    Worker Information is :
First Name : aze


    Do You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N
N
Please Enter The Worker's First Name : aze


    Worker Information is :
First Name : aze


    Do You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N
a
invalid answer


    Do You Approve Your Information ? Yes or No Enter Y or N
Y

Worker's information has been saved!
done
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that :

- why do you explicitly give the address of the string in your `scanf("%s"..)` ? the receiver must be an array of char and in that case the '&' is useless, else your code is invalid
- I encourage you to limit the number of chars *scanf* will write to avoid an undefined behavior if it writes out of the receiver, this is why I used `scanf("%31s", user.firstName)` knowing *firstName* is `char[32]`
- I also encourage you to check the result of all your *scanf* to be sure the input was correct
- I use `scanf(" %c", &answer)` to get a character, the space before `%c` allows to bypass the separators including the ones still buffered like the newline enter at the end of the previous input

---

After your edition :

warning now you have

> ```
>  scanf("%s", &answer);
>  if (scanf(" %c", &answer) != 1)
> ```

the first *scanf* must be removed.

Near the end you do

> ```
> scanf("%d",&answer1);
> ```

but you do not use answer1

Comment: I try to do ıt but ı can't understand Can you do it on my code? I must understand this and thanks for helping

Comment: @Exciless as you can see I did from your code. What do you not understand ?

Comment: I edit my code can you look my code again ? When I press the N or Y key, I need to write N or Y twice to make the process happen, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Exciless I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping